# Unity Input System does not work as needed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an New Input System that can control movement and rotation of troops and it does work for all accept one. When I try to move or rotate it Input does not work for him at all, so he just stand and do nothing and I want him to behave as all of the other troops(move and rotate)

[image: Problem]

I am pretty much sure the problem should be somewhere in a New Input settings somewhere, however I did not figure out on my own. The one thing a notice that ALWAYS ONLY the original Input setting does not work and the clones work fine, maybe this will help you to help me :D

Original input setting:

[image: original]

Clones:

[image: clones]

And for the last Input settings:

[image: Input settings]

I do not believe that a problem is in a code because it does work for all of them accept one, but I will put it here just in case.

```
    public void OnAttack(InputAction.CallbackContext context) => isShooting = context.performed;

    public void OnMove(InputAction.CallbackContext context) => moveDirection = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();

    public void OnLookAt(InputAction.CallbackContext context) => lookDirection = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Unity can not handle several Input components at the same time.